# Typeahead placing span tag after my label tag for my search. How can I add a label properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead.js

We have to be ADA compliant on our site. One of the things they look for is every form must have a label tag. The code has a label tag in the right place, but then when the javascript loads on the page, a span tag gets between the tag and the search field making it no longer compliant. I don't see a way to add a label. I was curious if anyone else had a suggestion for this or is there an alternative to typeahead that will work? In order to be compliant it must look like

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
```

For example the way it works now looks like...

```
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<span class="twitter-typeahead">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
</span>
```

Comment: why are you not using the "for" attribute?

Comment: for attribute? Where at? The label has a for attribute

Comment: the label has to have the id of the input in the for attribute, not the name

Comment: Sorry, just checked my code. I have the id as search. The id of the form is bloodhound. It's edited

Comment: Is the label has a for attribute, why would it need to be right beside the element? Seems like a bad validation since any screen reader can handle the tag with proper attributes linking it.

Comment: One of our customers is using a reader and has told us he has had issues with the search being read.

Comment: @TaylorMitchell Try substituting typeahead `substringMatcher` function for `.typeahead()` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191039/has-anyone-else-run-into-problems-styling-twitter-typeaheads-searchbar

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change the `span` tag that wraps your input. You can see where it is hardcoded in the source code [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/588440f66559714280628a4f9799f0c4eb880a4a/src/typeahead/www.js#L49). Unfortunately, typeahead is no longer maintained either, so there will not be a future option to customize this.

However, you can always modify the code yourself. Either in the `www.js` file that I linked to (if you compile yourself) or in the bundle, find the `buildHtml()` function and change that line to an empty string.

```
function buildHtml(c) {
    return {
      wrapper: '',
      menu: '<div class="' + c.menu + '"></div>'
    };
}
```

I don't know if this will have unknown repercussions elsewhere in typeahead, but I just tried it on a page and everything seemed to be working fine.