# creating an Input that updates constantly a list of words as soon as the user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an input to find words from a list. The instruction says that the find input field should contain the user's query. When the query is blank, the list box has to display the entire word, and whenever the query changes, the list box would immediately update to display all words that contain the query text (says how many words has been found). The list box should update constantly as the user types. Below is what I have come up with; I could not link the input (using a query) with the list of words; my "clear" bottom also does not work. Any suggestion on how to make it?

```
   <body>
   <div>
    Find: <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button>Clear</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function() {
            $("#Find").empty();
        });
    });
    </script>

    <select name="select" size="10" class="selection">
</select>
</div>

<script>
var words = [
    "a",
    "aabby",
    "about",
    "action"
];

$.each(words, function(i, word) {
    $(".selection").append("<option value='" + word + "'>" + word + "</option>");
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not express any sort of research.. Show us what is been tried and what is not working as you expect it to work..

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean a drop-down-selection like this:

```html
<input type="text" list="words" value=""></input>
<datalist id="words">
  <option value="a">
  <option value="aabby">
  <option value="about">
  <option value="action">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You for got to set the input tag's id to "Find".
The following will clear your input field.

```
$('#Find').val('');
```

For everything else here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f97dpad/)

That should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Added `id` attribute at `input` element set to `"Find"` , 
`label` element to display number of matches.

Substituted `.val()` for `.empty()` to clear `value` of `input` element.

You can use `input` event to update `select` `option` elements at each user input; create a function to call `$.each()` portion of existing `js`; utilize `String.prototype.split()` to match words, `$.grep()` to filter matches, `$.map()` to pass array of matched words to function that updates `html` at `label` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#Find").val("");
    update(words)
  });

  var words = [
    "a",
    "aabby",
    "about",
    "action"
  ];

  var selection = $(".selection"),
    input = $("input[type=search]"),
    label = $("label");

  function update(words) {
    selection.html("");
    $.each(words, function(i, word) {
      selection.append("<option value='" + word + "'>" + word + "</option>");
    });
    label.text("Results:" + selection.find("option").length);
  }

  input.on("input", function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value,
      keys = val.split(/\s+/),
      html = $.map(keys, function(key) {
      return $.grep(words, function(word) {
        return word === key 
        || word.slice(0, key.length) === key 
        || word.indexOf(key) > -1
      })
    });

    console.log(html);
    update(html);
  });
  
  update(words);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div>
  Find:

  <input id="Find" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  <label></label>
  <button>Clear</button>

  <script>
  </script>

  <select name="select" size="10" class="selection">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! But,  I was not aware there is an external js file that probably do the search task, so I looked for kinda easier and alternative ways for myself to understand which I uploaded under the main question in this page. But still not sure where I am wrong!

Comment: @Alex Does `js` at stacksnippets return expected results ? Search algorithms can vary depending on expected output results. _"so I looked for kinda easier"_ Not certain what "easier" means ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/29324737/

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with another way, since there is an external js file which includes the codes for searching.

var Dictionary = function(words) {

```
/**
 * Searches over this dictionary for the given query string. A word will
 * match if any substring of it matches the query. It is case-insensitive.
 *
 * @param query the substring to search for
 * @returns an array of the results that contain the query substring
 */
this.search = function(query) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(query, "i");
    return $.grep(words, function(w) {
        return pattern.test(w);
    });
};

/**
 * Returns the total number of words in this dictionary
 *
 * @returns the number of words in this dictionary
 */
this.size = function() {
    return words.length;
}

/**
 * Returns an array of all of the words in this dictionary
 *
 * @returns an array of all of the words in this dictionary
 */
this.all = function() {
    return words;
}
```

}

And this is my html codes; however I could not understand why it does not search for inputs and do not update the "#WordCounter".

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dictionary.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

  
var words= [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition",
    "adjustment",
    "advertisement",
    
];



 function updateWordList(){
 $("#inputText").val("");
 $("#selection").empty();
 
   $.each(words, function (key, value) {
    $("#selection").append($("<option/>").val(key).text(value));
    });
 }
 
 

 function partialWordList(searchResults){
 $("#selection").empty();
 
  
    $.each(searchResults, function (key, value) {
    $("#inputText").append($("<option/>").val(key).text(value));
 
  
    });

}

 $(document).ready(function() {
 var dict = new Dictionary(words);
 
 

});
 
 updateWordList();
 $("#inputText").on("change paste keyup",function(){
  var partialWord=$(this).val();
  var searchResults= dict.search(partialWord);
  partialWordList(searchResults);
  
 var len=searchResults.length;
 $("#WordCounter".text(len+"contain"+$("#inputText").val()));
  

   $("#clear").click(updateWordList);
 
});

</script>
```

```css
html {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
     div{
        width:400px;
        margin:40px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
    }
 select{
  width:400px;
        margin:40px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;

 }
```

```html
<body>

<div>Find: 
  <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="Search..."/>
  <button id= "clearButton">Clear</button>

    
    <p id= "WordCounter">10 words in total</p>
    <select size="7" id="selection" >
    </select>
  </div>
  
  </body>
```